# Attribute Error: scipy has no attribute 'stats'

Tags: python, scipy

Estou obtendo esse erro ao tentar importar a biblioteca Pyfolio, tentei importar primeiro:

```
import scipy.stats
```

ou

```
from scipy import stats
```

e não obtive sucesso. Consigo importar o scipy mas na hora de importar novamente a biblioteca Pyfolio aparece o mesmo erro.

```
import scipy.stats import pyfolio as pf
```

Tentei instalar novamente scipy (via pip), tentei também atualizá-la mas não deu certo.Estou usando Python Versão 3.6.5, Windows, codando no Spyder. Alguém sabe como consigo arrumar esse erro?

Comment: Arthur, boa noite! Qual o nome do seu arquivo.py?

Answer (score -2):

tenta importar a função
use:

```
from scipy import stats
```

se não resolver, achei uma solucao na thread da gringa com mesma pergunta:

[Click aqui para ir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469734/import-scipy-stats-error)